# Can I change the language display of the skype button?

Tags: c#, api, skype

In my C# application, I'm using the `mystatus.skype.com/xxxxx` to get the user's status as an image and then load in a `PictureBox` but I'd like to be able to show it in others languages as available in `mystatus.skype.com/xxxxx.xml` but I can't find the documentation of `mystatus.skype.com` neither in the Skype nor [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745878) site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any official documentation on this, but it seems like you can append the language as the extension to get a localized variant of the image. For example: `http://mystatus.skype.com/xxxxx.ja`